# Is there a good reason to have short file names for javascripts?

Tags: javascript

Eg. why is the google analytics script, ga.js instead of google-analytics.js?

Is it convention, optimisation or over optimisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google analytics is used by A LOT of sites. While usually saving a few bytes in a path is clearly over-optimization it does make sense in this a case.

Answer (score 1):

Less characters to travel over the wire and get parsed by the client. It's not a big difference, but everything helps.

Answer (score 0):

Millions of sites use Google Analytics. They probably want to save every byte of bandwidth.

Or it was just a random choice. Short URLs are easier to remember, too.